# 'npm i' results in "Error: Missing required argument #1"

Tags: npm, node-modules

I am trying to install npm packages, but when I run `npm i`, I get the following:

```
loadDep:next → resolveWit ▀ ╢████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:next → get        ▐ ╢████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine firebase-admin@8.13.0: wanted: {"node":"^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine firebase-functions@3.13.2: wanted: {"node":"^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
loadDep:next → resolveWit ▐ ╢████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:@ctrl/tinycolor → ▀ ╢████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:@firebase/util →  ▌ ╢██████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:@grpc/proto-loade ▄ ╢██████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:semver → afterAdd ▐ ╢██████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:lru-cache → get   ▐ ╢██████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine gtoken@5.2.1: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine gcp-metadata@4.2.1: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine gaxios@4.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
loadDep:google-p12-pem →  ▌ ╢██████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:@google-cloud/sto ▀ ╢███████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I have tried reinstalling Node.js and stuff like that, but right now I am at a loss what to do.

> node -v = v12.20.2

> npm -v = 3.5.2

How do I go about figuring this out? Or is there an obvious issue?

Also, what does this mean:

```
WARN engine firebase-admin@8.13.0: wanted: {"node":"^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
```

Because I have v12 as seen from my *node -v* response.

Comment: Try installing them manually, like `npm i --save -dev @firebase/admin` or `npm install --save express-session` or whatever your module is.

Comment: it says this for example: `WARN engine sharp@0.26.3: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})` but i dont have any sharp package in my package.json

Comment: run `npm -v` to check your node version. From what you said, it seems out of date. Try also running `npm uninstall sharp@0.26.3` if you are not using it.

Comment: Update: downgraded to node v12.16.1 and it worked

Comment: so is your problem solved?

Comment: Ahh yes I came back to this and it is probably running sharp as a dependency to one of your modules.

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded to Node.js v12.16.1 and it worked.